# Count bidirectional edges between 2 nodes performed on the entire graph

Tags: neo4j

I have a weighted graph which has bidirectional relations between some nodes. I want to find the nodes which have the bidirectional relation and based on weight (the edge with the higher number will remain, the other edge I want to delete) to delete the edge with the lower number.

```
START n1=node(*), n2=node(*)
MATCH (n1)-[r:HAS_CHILD]-(n2) where (n1)-[r]->(n2)and (n1)<-[r]-(n2)
RETURN n1,r,n2 limit 10;
```

This query is displaying the nodes with relationship to itself, I want the nodes which have bidirectional relations between them and then delete the edge with the lower number displayed on edge.

I expect to have no bidirectional relations between nodes based on the number from an edge. If I have (n)-[r{weight:2}]->(m) and (n)<-[r{weight:4}]-(m) then the remaining edge will be the one with weight 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relationships are not bi-directional in Neo4j, so there are two different relationships in this case.

But you are trying to match single relationship in WHERE clause which is directed towards both n1 and n2, which is only possible if n1 and n2 are the same nodes, that is why it's displaying the nodes with relationship to itself.

Try this:

> Refer relationship from n1 to n2 as r1 AND relationship from n2 to n1 as r2
>   and compare them

```
MATCH (n1)-[r1:HAS_CHILD]->(n2)-[r2:HAS_CHILD]->(n1) 
RETURN n1,r1,r2,n2 limit 10;
```

Hope this helps you.

**EDIT:**

Compare relationship weights before deleting.

```
MATCH (n1)-[r1:HAS_CHILD]->(n2)-[r2:HAS_CHILD]->(n1) 
WHERE r1.weight <= r2.weight
DELETE r1;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. This will find the nodes with "bidirectional" relationship and i have another query which will delete the relationship, I checked  on a sample data and it is working. Do you think this query will delete always the edge with lower weight?   MATCH (a:Disease)-[r]-(b:Disease)
WITH a, b, collect(r) as rels
UNWIND tail(rels) as rel
DELETE rel;

Comment: On my sample data is deleting always the one with lower weight but I dont specify anywhere which edge should be deleted.

Comment: I think this may cause some issues. I suggest you compare the values before delete

Comment: How can I compare the values ?

Comment: MATCH (a:Disease)-[r]-(b:Disease)
WITH a, b, collect(r) as rels
UNWIND tail(rels) as rel
with a.rel<b.rel as operator
when operator then 
DELETE a.rel
else DELETE b.rel;

Comment: I tried this but I have a syntax error, I am thinking as this is a programming language as python, but this is not the correct way of thinking. Anyway Ray you helped me a lot, I started with neo4j 2 months ago and I already know a lot.

Comment: Still a syntax error : Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'n': expected 'r/R' (line 1, column 122 (offset: 121))
"MATCH (a:Disease)-[r]-(b:Disease) WITH a, b, collect(r) as rels UNWIND tail(rels) as rel with a.rel<b.rel as operator when operator then DELETE a.rel else DELETE b.rel;"

Comment: Please check EDIT in the answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! All works how is supposed to.